# I want to preview HTML form data in pop window before submit. How to do that using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, web

Following is my HTML Code having two buttons, Preview and Submit. I want to pop a window showing form preview when  click on Preview and then submit the form when I click on Submit.

```
    <form action="">
    <div class="search-form">
        <div class="form-header">
            <h4>Post a New Job</h4>
        </div>

        <label for="job_title">Job Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" placeholder="Hiring for which position">


        <label for="company">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Name of the hiring organization">


       
        <label for="experience-required">Total Experience Required</label>
        <div class="input-range">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="50" name="experience-required-min" id="experience-required-min"
                placeholder="Min in Years">
            <span>To</span>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="50" name="experience-required-max" id="experience-required-max"
                placeholder="Max in Years">
        </div>
        <label for="salary-range">Salary Range</label>
        <div class="input-range">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="50" name="salary-range-min" id="salary-range-min"
                placeholder="Min in Lpa">
            <span>To</span>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="50" name="salary-range-max" id="salary-range-max"
                placeholder="Min in Lpa">

        </div>
        
        </div>
        <label for="job-desciption">Job Description</label>
        <textarea name="job-desciption" class="input-range" placeholder="Enter Job Desciption"
            style="height: 100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>
    <a href="" <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="submit" name="search">Post</button>
    </a>
    <a href="" <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="submit" name="search">Preview</button>
    </a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using modals , you can use Bootstrap or Materialize css I'll link them below.

Bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/

materialize
https://materializecss.com/modals.html#!

After you implement a modal in your app you can easily use it's buttons to submit your form or cancel.

please let me know if this hepled

Answer (score 0):

First, the preview button `type` should be `button` and not submit. Button with `type` as `submit` causes the form to submit. Also, do not wrap the button within the `<a>` anchor tag. That is unnecessary.

```
<!-- Note the use of type="button" -->
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="button" name="search">Preview</button>
```

Second, you will need a JavaScript code to handle click handler. You can do something like this:

```
// Get reference to the preview button
const previewButton = document.querySelector('.search-form button[type="button"]');

previewButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

  // Step 1: Read form data here using DOM APIs

  // Step 2: Open preview using some modal dialog.
  window.alert(/* Show form data */);

  // Or use some other bootstrap or equivalent library dialog box.

});
```

There are many ways to write the JavaScript. Choose one that works best for you.